# Concatenate pseudo & class variable

Tags: jquery, viewport, pseudo-element

I'm using the [viewport selectors](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport) jQuery plugin, and trying to perform the same task on a few elements:

```
$('#something').each(function(){
    var current = $(this);
    if ($(this + ':in-viewport')){
        console.log(current.attr('id'));
    }
});
```

Am I doing something horribly wrong? This is the error my console is spitting out:

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLDivElement]:in-viewport`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're concatenating `this` which is an `object` to `:in-viewport` which is a `string`, and so the object is being converted `toString` and the result is `[object HTMLDivElement]:in-viewport`, which is an illegal `jQuery selector`.

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
$('#something').each(function(){
    var current = $(this);
    if ($(this).is(':in-viewport')) {
        console.log(current.attr('id'));
    }
});
```

Or in a better version of this *specific* code:

```
$('#something:in-viewport').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```